# Как записать token из header в localstorage?

Tags: reactjs

Не получается записать token из headers. Серверная часть написана на java, где создается сам token, config:

```
@Component
public class CrosFilterConfig implements Filter {

public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With");
    chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
}
```

React fetch:

```
    handleSubmit(event){
  event.preventDefault();
 fetch('http://localhost:8080/login',{
  method: 'POST',
  mode:'no-cors',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
  },
  body:JSON.stringify({
    'username' : this.state.username,
    'password' : this.state.password
  }
  )
}).then(response => {
  if (response.ok){

  }
let token = response.token;
let user = localStorage.setItem('Authorization', token)
console.log(user);
});
};
```

Сам токен:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А в LocalStorage:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что-то вы не то приводите, или не оттуда. В примере устанавливаете ключ `Authorization`, а в хранилище `Key: 'token'`. Значит где-то еще есть кусок кода, который пишет в хранилище `setItem('token', null)`

Comment: да, ошибся, сделал правку в коде на сайте

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в ваш then console.log(response) чтобы точно знать что приходит и напишите что там сюда

обычно в первом then возврашают response.json()
потом добавляют ещё один

Примерно так

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
  localStorage.setItem('Authorization', token: data.token)
})
```

Comment: Пишет ошибку: Unhandled Rejection (SyntaxError): Unexpected end of input, указывая на данную строку fetch('http://localhost:8080/login',{
Что касаемо console.log(response):
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 0
statusText: ""
type: "opaque"
url: ""
__proto__: Response